# Why can't i set a member variable of an interface class as follows

Tags: c++, inheritance, variables, interface, declaration

So i have a interface class

```
class interfaceClass
{
 public:   
    virtual void func1( void ) = 0;
    virtual void func2( void ) = 0;

protected:
    int m_interfaceVar;
}
```

and a class that inherits from it.
Why can't i set the member variable of the interface class as follows.

```
class inhertitedClass : public interfaceClass
{
   inheritedClass(int getInt): m_interfaceVar(getInt){};
   ~inheritedClass(){};
}
```

and i have to do it like this

```
class inhertitedClass : public interfaceClass
{
   inheritedClass(int getInt){ m_interfaceVar = getInt;}
   ~inheritedClass(){};
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but i just ran in to it the other night while i was switching my abstract class into an interface class (the back to an abstract class).

Comment: can i even have a variable in an interface class? It has been too long since i wrote one.

Comment: initialization error on the variable i was trying to access.

Comment: That member variable doesn't belong in the class.  Since all of the methods are abstract, there isn't any reason to not move it to the derived class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initializer list in a constructor can specify the ctor for the **base classes** first and foremost.  By depriving `interfaceClass` of a (protected) constructor (which it obviously *should* have) you've cut off that lifeline.

So add that protected ctor, e.g.:

```
class interfaceClass
{
 public:   
    virtual void func1( void ) = 0;
    virtual void func2( void ) = 0;

protected:
    int m_interfaceVar;
    interfaceClass(int x) { m_interfaceVar=x; }
}
```

and *then* you can do things the right way, namely

```
class inhertitedClass : public interfaceClass
{
   inheritedClass(int getInt): interfaceClass(getInt){};
   ~inheritedClass(){};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

By the time `inheritedClass` gets to it's initializer list, `m_interfaceVar` has already been initialized.  You can't initialize it a second time.

Your options are to provide a constructor to `interfaceClass` that initializes `m_interfaceVar`, or just assign it in the body of `inheritedClass`s constructor:

```
 interfaceClass(int getInt) : interfaceVar(getInt){}
 ...
 inheritedClass(int getInt) : interfaceClass(getInt)
 {
 }
```

or

```
 inheritedClass(int getInt)
 {
    m_interfaceVar = getInt;
 }
```

Comment: i thought interface classes shouldn't have constructors?

Comment: There's nothing special about abstract classes in C++ except that you can't directly create an instance of one.  In fact, if you don't provide a constructor, the compiler will fill some in for you.

Comment: @Craig: An interface shouldn't be directly instantiable, so it shouldn't have a *public* constructor.

Comment: If a class has member attributes, they should be initialized and as such a constructor is appropriate (unless the default constructor suffices)

Comment: @Scott Smith: If the class has pure virtual methods, it cannot be instantiated anyway by any but deriving classes that override those virtuals. Now, the one thing that the code is missing is having a protected destructor or a public virtual one, depending on the expected usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
class interfaceClass
{
public:   
    virtual void func1( void ) = 0;
    virtual void func2( void ) = 0;

protected:
    // Ctor - called from derived classes
    interfaceClass(int interfaceVar)
        : m_interfaceVar(interfaceVar){};

    int m_interfaceVar;
}

class inhertitedClass : public interfaceClass
{
   inheritedClass(int getInt)
       : interfaceClass(getInt){}; // Pass to base class ctor

   ~inheritedClass(){};
}
```

...in fact, if you *don't* create a protected or private constructor for `interfaceClass`, the compiler will silently create one for you, and users will be able to create instances of your interface (you did want it to be an abstract base class, right?)

Comment: Users will not be able to create instances of the interface anyway: pure virtual methods make the class abstract and you cannot instantiate an abstract class. Havint the constructor public or protected will not actually make any difference.